# imbue/facet ignored when used from shared libraries under Windows

Tags: c++, boost

I had a wierd behaviour with `facet` passed to `std::ostream` through `imbue` being ignored in a very specific architecture under Android ([imbue/facet ignored when used from shared libraries depending on dynamic load order under Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784836/imbue-facet-ignored-when-used-from-shared-libraries-depending-on-dynamic-load-or)).

While trying to workaround the unresolved issue, I could reproduce the issue under Windows with a much easier architecture. And this is much more surprising to hit this issue in such a simple MCVE:

I declare a shared library linking statically to boost date_time:

*bug_datetime_libwin.h:*

```
#pragma once

#ifdef BUG_DATETIME_LIBWIN_EXPORTS
    #define BUG_DATETIME_LIBWIN_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define BUG_DATETIME_LIBWIN_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <ostream>

class BUG_DATETIME_LIBWIN_API BoostFacets
{
public:
    static void SetupStream( std::ostream& str );
    static void PrintTime( std::ostream& str );
};
```

*bug_datetime_libwin.cpp:*

```
#include "bug_datetime_libwin.h"

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning( disable: 4005 ) // if one already included math.h, we get duplicated macro defeinition warnings
#endif
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif

#define READABLE_DATE_FORMAT "%Y-%b-%d"
#define READABLE_TIME_FORMAT_ACC "%H:%M:%s"

void BoostFacets::SetupStream( std::ostream& str )
{
    static std::string accurateFormat = std::string(READABLE_DATE_FORMAT) + " " + READABLE_TIME_FORMAT_ACC;
    
    boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet(accurateFormat.c_str());
    str.imbue(std::locale(str.getloc(), facet));
}

void BoostFacets::PrintTime( std::ostream& str )
{
    SetupStream( str );
    boost::posix_time::ptime t1(boost::gregorian::date(2002,boost::gregorian::Jan,10),
                                boost::posix_time::time_duration(1,2,4));
    str << t1;
}
```

Then I have an application linking dynamically to the shared library and statically to boost date_time:

*main.cpp:*

```
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

#include "bug_datetime_libwin/bug_datetime_libwin.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    {
        std::stringstream temp;
        BoostFacets::PrintTime( temp );

        std::cout << "PrintTime: " << temp.str().c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::stringstream temp;
        BoostFacets::SetupStream( temp );

        boost::posix_time::ptime t1(boost::gregorian::date(2002,boost::gregorian::Jan,10),
                                    boost::posix_time::time_duration(1,2,4));
        temp << t1;

        std::cout << "SetupStream: " << temp.str().c_str() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This function outputs:

```
PrintTime: 2002-Jan-10 01:02:04.000000
SetupStream: 2002-Jan-10 01:02:04
```

As you can see, if the lib does an `imbue` on a stream, creates a `boost::posix_time::ptime` object and prints it to the stream, it works fine.

But if lib does an `imbue` on a stream, and the application creates a `boost::posix_time::ptime` object and prints it to the string, it does not work fine: `imbue` has no effect!

What am I doing wrong?

---

Update 1:

Tried to compile boost as shared libraries to prevent ODR violation as proposed by Alan Birtles. It did not fix the issue. Actually, boost does not even need to be linked for this code to work as used mincludes are "header-only". So the issue is not due to static boost linkage.

---

Update 2:

I used the debugger to see what's going on:

The issue comes from:

```
template <class CharT, class TraitsT>
  inline
  std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>&
  operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>& os,
             const ptime& p) {
    boost::io::ios_flags_saver iflags(os);
    typedef boost::date_time::time_facet<ptime, CharT> custom_ptime_facet;
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<CharT> oitr(os);
    if (std::has_facet<custom_ptime_facet>(os.getloc()))
      std::use_facet<custom_ptime_facet>(os.getloc()).put(oitr, os, os.fill(), p);
    else {
      //instantiate a custom facet for dealing with times since the user
      //has not put one in the stream so far.  This is for efficiency 
      //since we would always need to reconstruct for every time period
      //if the locale did not already exist.  Of course this will be overridden
      //if the user imbues as some later point.
      custom_ptime_facet* f = new custom_ptime_facet();
      std::locale l = std::locale(os.getloc(), f);
      os.imbue(l);
      f->put(oitr, os, os.fill(), p);
    }
    return os;
  }
```

in posix_time_io.hpp.

- When main calls `PrintTime`, it calls `SetupStream`, here created `facet` id (`boost::posix_time::time_facet::id`) is `5`
- Then when `SetupStream` calls `str << t1`, `custom_ptime_facet`, in posix_time_io.hpp's `operator<<`, has an `id` value of `5`, so `has_facet` resturns `true` and string gets formatted.
- When main calls `SetupStream`, here created `facet` id (`boost::posix_time::time_facet::id`) is still `5`
- But when `main` calls `str << t1`, `custom_ptime_facet`, in posix_time_io.hpp's `operator<<`, has an `id` value of `44`, so `has_facet` resturns `false` and string does not get formatted.

I suspect this is because `posix_time_io.hpp` is included twice:

- once from the library, assigning static `custom_ptime_facet::id` to `5`
- once from the program, assigning static `custom_ptime_facet::id` to `44`

So I tested, and doing this at the end of the MCVE's main function:

```
{
    static std::string accurateFormat = std::string(READABLE_DATE_FORMAT) + " " + READABLE_TIME_FORMAT_ACC;

    std::stringstream temp;
    boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet(accurateFormat.c_str());
    temp.imbue(std::locale(temp.getloc(), facet));

    boost::posix_time::ptime t1(boost::gregorian::date(2002,boost::gregorian::Jan,10),
                                boost::posix_time::time_duration(1,2,4));
    temp << t1;

    std::cout << "main: " << temp.str().c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

outputs `PrintTime: 2002-Jan-10 01:02:04.000000`. It works because `facet` created here has an `id` of `44`, then `has_facet` returns true.

**Does that mean that, by construction, because it uses header-only approach, boost date time won't allow one module to set `imbue` and another to use `operator<<`?**

Comment: is your whole application and all libraries linked to a single shared c++ runtime? Symptoms smell like an ODR violation

Comment: Actually re-reading your question, you are linking to two separate static copies of boost date_time, so definitely have an ODR violation

Comment: @AlanBirtles: So how should I fix that? As both the lib and the app needs boost, must I compile and link boost as shared libraries?

Comment: yes, you need to use shared libraries or statically link your lib into your application

Comment: @AlanBirtles: See my updates, the problem apparently does not come from linking machanism!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an ODR violation. As `boost::posix_time::time_facet` is a header only template, each translation unit gets its own copy of the template instantiations. The linker merges any duplicates into a single object when creating a shared library or executable. However the existence of the object inside the shared library is not visible to the linker when creating the executable so the executable gets its own copy of the object. This then means there are two separate instances of the static `std::locale::id id` member which the standard library (correctly) assigns different values.

To fix the issue you have to both export `time_facet` from your shared library and make sure that your executable uses the shared library version rather than creating its own copy.

In your shared library in one translation unit add:

```
template class __declspec(dllexport)
boost::date_time::time_facet<boost::posix_time::ptime, char>;
```

In your application after including boost but before any instantiations of the facet add:

```
template class __declspec(dllimport)
boost::date_time::time_facet<boost::posix_time::ptime, char>;
```

There are many pitfalls in interoperating with c++ objects over shared library boundaries. Its much easier to statically link everything into a single executable.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Alan's answer is to make sure this code is compiled once only.

So I created a new library `boost_datetime` with:

**boost_datetime.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <ostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

namespace boost
{
    namespace posix_time
    {
        class ptime;
    }
}

class BoostDateTime
{
public:
    static void setFacet( std::ostream& os );
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const boost::posix_time::ptime& p );
```

**boost_datetime.cpp:**

```
#include "boost_datetime.h"

void BoostDateTime::setFacet( std::ostream& os )
{
    boost::posix_time::time_facet* facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%Y$%b$%d %H:%M:%S.%f");
    os.imbue(std::locale(os.getloc(), facet));
}

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const boost::posix_time::ptime& p )
{
    // copied from posix_time_io.hpp

    boost::io::ios_flags_saver iflags(os);
    typedef boost::posix_time::time_facet base_ptime_facet;
    std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> oitr(os);
    if (std::has_facet<base_ptime_facet>(os.getloc()))
      std::use_facet<base_ptime_facet>(os.getloc()).put(oitr, os, os.fill(), p);
    else {
      //instantiate a custom facet for dealing with times since the user
      //has not put one in the stream so far.  This is for efficiency 
      //since we would always need to reconstruct for every time period
      //if the locale did not already exist.  Of course this will be overridden
      //if the user imbues as some later point.
      base_ptime_facet* f = new base_ptime_facet();
      std::locale l = std::locale(os.getloc(), f);
      os.imbue(l);
      f->put(oitr, os, os.fill(), p);
    }
    return os;
}
```

Use it in every place instead of directly using boost date_time. This fixes the issue for good.